# How Can I do a multiple Split

Tags: c#

How can I do a multiple Split ?

**Example**

`string eq = SIN(X)/3`

I can SPLIT this like `string equation[] = eq.Split['/']` but if I have `+, -, *, /` in my equation how can I SPLIT this ?

**Example**

`string eq = SIN(X) + 3 / 3 * 4`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: If you're looking to evaluate mathematical expressions, you should try [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Please show expected output of your example string. `Split` generally drops separator characters... If you are looking for tokenization `Split` is likely not enough.

Comment: Baboon How can I set NCalc to Radians ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) allows to pass in multiple characters:

```
var result = eq.Split('/', '+', '-', '*');
```

Having said that, it is not a good idea to evaluate such expressions by using string operations. You should use a mathematical parser for this task.

Comment: I need calc the SIN first or any expression before the calc of the rest of my equation

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Regex.Split**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx) and use the regex to match the operators e.g. below:

```
string[] equation = Regex.Split(eq, "[/\+\*-]");
```

Supply all possible operators in the regex expression.

Comment: @L.B I added the escape chars in the regex.  What do you mean by `Neither C#`? I already provided a link of the documentation.

Comment: `string equation[]` or `string[] equation` ?

Comment: @L.B oops That I copied from OP's post. Ignore it. Corrected.